# C++11 making variadic constructor understand an initialization list of initialization lists

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Let's say I have a class of Point and and an array of Points, where the number of points is given by a template parameter. How do I get initialization to work using braces? 
If I use:

```
class Point {
public:
    float x, y;
    Point(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

template <size_t N>
class Array {
private:
    std::array<Point, N> _points;

public:
    template <typename... Points>
    Array(const Points& ... points) : _points({ points... }) {
    }
};
```

Then this works:

```
Array<2> a{Point{1,1}, Point{2, 2}};
```

But If I don't provide explicit `Point` objects, I get an error in Xcode:

```
Array<2> c{{1,1}, {2, 2}};
```

The error is: "No matching Constructor for initialization of Array<2>". For the particular constructor it says "Candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided".

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Simplest way is to use an `initializer_list<Point>` constructor instead.

Comment: @T.C. That doesn't work here, unless there's some other trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Why doesn't your code work

You're bracing in a *braced-init-list*, `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}`. That thing doesn't have a type. It's just a collection of stuff. Template deduction can't really work because that could be *anything* - there is an infinite amount of types that could be constructed from that list. Even though you clearly want `Points...` to be `Point`s, that just can't work.

#### What do to instead

The only way to take a *braced-init-list* to mean an arbitrary amount of `T`s (for some type `T`) is to use `std::initializer_list`:

```
Array(std::initializer_list<Point> points) { ... }
```

But to initialize the array from the `initializer_list`, you'd need something like `std::copy`, but since `Point` isn't default-constructible, this is a non-starter unfortunately<sup>†</sup>.

We could instead just take an array directly:

```
Array(std::array<Point, N> const& a)
    : _points(a)
{ }
```

That lets you do what you want. Or at least, with a few extra braces:

```
Array<2> c{{{{1, 1}, {2,2}}}};
```

That is an annoyingly excessive amount of braces!

So one trick I like instead is to actually create a constructor that takes `N` `Point`s, which is what you wanted to begin with. We can do that by making `Array` a partial specialization with the index sequence trick:

```
template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
class Array;

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
class Array<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
private:
    std::array<Point, N> _points;

    template <size_t>
    using Point_ = Point;

public:
    Array(Point_<Is>... points)
        : _points{{points...}}
    { }
};
```

Here, `Point_<I>` is just an alias template for `Point`, we use it just to unpack the index sequence into a bunch of `Point`s. That constructor is thus a *non*-template that takes precisely `N` `Point`s and we can then use it with a sane amount of braces:

```
Array<2> c{{1, 1}, {2,2}}; // ok!
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Well, not really a non-starter. There's several things you can do to still get this to work. You could make `Point` default-constructible, at which point you could write:

```
Array(std::initializer_list<Point> il)
{
    std::copy(il.begin(), il.begin() + std::min(il.size(), N),  _points.begin());
}
```

Or even without making `Point` default-constructible, you could use the index sequence trick to initialize with the help of a delegating constructor:

```
public:
    Array(std::initializer_list<Point> il)
        : Array(il, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    { }

private:
    template <size_t... Is>
    Array(std::initializer_list<Point> il, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
        : _points{{(Is < il.size() ? il.begin()[Is] : Point(0,0))...}}
    { }
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that `Point` isn't default constructible (which is a little silly, but whatever). You can still use pack expansion with `index_sequence` to initialize from an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @T.C. But you don't know how long it is at compile time.

Comment: You have to populate the whole array, still. So something along the lines of `{ (Is < list.size()? list.begin()[Is] : Point(0, 0))... }`.

Comment: @T.C. Oh that seems so obvious in retrospect.

Comment: Well, this got me what I wanted. But it looks like even more magic, deeper down the rabbit hole ;-).
Why does Array have two template parameters? And somehow there's a default filled in. Also, I have never seen the templated "using" -- where does that size_t even get used?

Comment: @Ant6n We don't use the `size_t` - we just use that template alias to unpack the indices (0, 1, 2, ..., N-1) into Points (Point, Point, Point, ..., Point).

Comment: I tried to use this, this doesn't compile in XCode (already at the `class = std::make_index_sequence<N>`). I think this may be C++14.

Comment: @Ant6n It is C++14, yes. You can implement it in C++11 though (just search around here for solutions).